# git command alias in gitconfig: what characters to escape

Tags: git

This git command works well in `git bash`

```
$ git log --author="\(david\)\|\(peter\)" --format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
```

But when I put it into my `gitconfig`:

```
$ grep -E -e "alias|lolaf" .gitconfig
[alias]
        lolaf   = log --author="(david)|(peter)" --format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)" --pretty=format:'%h %\\<(22)%an %s'
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)" --format="%h %\\<(22)%an %s"
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)" --format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
        # lolaf = log --author="\(david\)\|\(peter\)" --format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
        # lolaf = log --author="(david)|(peter)" --pretty-format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
```

I got this error

```
$ git lolaf -- .
fatal: bad revision '%<(22)%an'
```

I believe the problem is due to the wrong escaping of special characters.  As you can see I tried a few different variants but they also did not work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If it is trying to parse `'%<(22)%an'` as a revision, my guess would be that the quotes around `--format` are to blame.  (i.e. I think it is trying to pass `'%<(22)%an'` as an argument to `log` rather than keeping it as part of the format string)

Comment: @0x5453 -- Thanks!  I have found the right combination.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I am providing my own answer here.  Just in this case this may help someone.)

After many more trials, I finally find the right combination.

1. Use single quote to escape `<`
2. Use single quote and double backslash `\\` to replace the single backslash used in `git bash`

So,

```
lolaf   = log --author='\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)' --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
```

Below the first one worked, the other were results of my experimentation:

```
$ grep -E -e "alias|lolaf|worked" .gitconfig
[alias]
        lolaf   = log --author='\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)' --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
        # this worked
        # lolaf = log --author='\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)'
        # lolaf = log --author='\\(david\\)|\\(peter\\)'
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)|\\(peter\\)"
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)"
        # lolaf = log --author="david\\|peter" --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)" --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
        # this worked
        # lolaf = log --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)" --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
        # lolaf = log --author="\(david\)\|\(peter\)" --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
        # lolaf = log --author='(david)|(peter)' --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
        # lolaf = log --author="(david)|(peter)" --format='%h %<(22)%an %s'
        # lolaf = log --author="(david)|(peter)" --format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)" --pretty=format:'%h %\\<(22)%an %s'
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)" --format="%h %\\<(22)%an %s"
        # lolaf = log --author="\\(david\\)\\|\\(peter\\)" --format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
        # lolaf = log --author="\(david\)\|\(peter\)" --format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
        # lolaf = log --author="(david)|(peter)" --pretty-format="%h %<(22)%an %s"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was getting an error because on of my alias commands had square bracket, using double backslash to escape it, fixed it